# Timer Based Application In GWTP

Tags: gwt

I want to create a `GWT` application. That whenever the user gets logged in to system, it will show some information in PopUpPanel and after some time it gets disabled automatically.Is it possible with `GWT` ?

Comment: GWT has a timer class for time based scheduling tasks at client side.  You can take advantage of it.  http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.4/com/google/gwt/user/client/Timer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could try something like:

```
Timer t = new Timer() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            popUpPanel.hide();
          }
        };
    popUpPanel.show();
t.schedule(5000);
```

Where `5000` is how long you want to show the pop up for.